# How to perform sql select query with additional fields in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the next model:

```
[Table("clients")]
    public class ClientDto : BaseModelDto
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(70, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Column("fio")]
        public string FIO { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Column("address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Phone]
        [Column("phone")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }        

        public List<RealizationDto> Realizations { get; set; }
    }
```

And I need to perform sql query and get the result:

```
public async Task<ClientDto> GetTheMostValuableCustomer()
    {
      var result = await Context.Clients.FromSql<ClientDto>(@"
        select clients.id, clients.fio, clients.address, clients.phone, sum(goods.price*realizations.quantity) max_cost
            from clients
            inner join realizations on clients.id=realizations.client_id
            inner join goods on realizations.good_id=goods.id
            group by clients.id
            order by max_cost desc
        limit 1;
    ").ToListAsync();

  return result.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This quesry works in PostgreSql, but doesn't work on server level, because ClientDto model and select fields are different. (max_cost doesn't exist in ClientDto model). But when I execute query I get an error that the field "max_cost" doesn't exist. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: What if you move the `max_cost` to the order by instead of the select list?. e.g. `order by sum(goods.price*realizations.quantity)`

Comment: Which database provider is this?

Comment: @Gert Arnold PostgreSQL

Comment: @D Stanley I need this field in my program

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
sum(goods.price*realizations.quantity) max_cost
```

to:

```
sum(goods.price*realizations.quantity) AS max_cost
```

Comment: I think these constructions are equaled